# when should add mixin keyword in dart OOP

Tags: flutter, dart, mixins

i have here two examples, both of them are works well:

```
    class A {
     int sum(){}
    }

   class B with A {}
```

and

```
 mixin A {
     int sum(){}
    }

   class B with A {}
```

what is the difference ?

Comment: mixin allows you to share pieces of code without inheritance, you can use a normal class as mixin in the case of your first examples only if the class does not have a constructor, another advantages of mixin over class is that classes does not support multiple inheritance but you can use as many mixins as possible in a single class, also another difference is that you can cast an child class to a parent class but you can't do that with mixins

Comment: you use mixin when you just want to share a pieces of code between related or unrelated classes without worrying about inheritance, also use mixins if you want to inherit a lot of classes because ideally you can't inherent more than one class in a regular class

Comment: i didn't see any difference, for the constructor or multi inheritance, same with class or mixin if we just use with ....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after some searches, I found only one important difference between a regular class and using mixin keyword...

the class with mixin keyword cannot be instantiated.

which means we cannot create an object from it

Answer (score 0):

Mixin is class that contains method which can be used by other class without and parent-child relation.

As per wikipedia, mixin is "include" Instead of "inherit".

1. Mixin encourage code reusability.
2. no parent to child relationship
3. it's not inheritance so remove the ambiguity of multiple inheritance.

Note: don't include many mixin in one class because it is difficult to distinguish which method is from which mixin.

Q) What if two or more included mixin have method with name name?

A) Then the last mixin's having same method will run (tried in dart).

---

But i still don't get why we need mixin when we have static methods. And when to use what.

Comment: I am also learning these advance OOPS concept, so please correct me if I am wrong.